# program for calculating x raised to the power of y using while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

```
int main()
{ unsigned int x, y;

    printf_s("Enter value for x: ");
    scanf_s("%u", &x);

    printf_s("Enter value for y: ");
    scanf_s("%u", &y);

    unsigned int count = 1;
    while (count < y);
    {
        x *= x;
        count++;
    }

    printf_s("x raised to the power of y is: %u", x);
}
```

Hi, I'm not sure where I went wrong.
When I run it, I enter two values as prompted and then nothing else happens.
It just stops after I enter they value for y.

Enter value for x: 3
Enter value for y: 2

Like this. Could someone point me in the right direction?
I understand that this way will not work if y <= 1.
But shouldn't it work for when y > 1?

I've searched for it. There is another question using for loop.
I can see that it could be done with for loop but I think while loop is more appropriate since it gives more freedom.
Please and thank you!

Comment: Note the `;` in `while (count < y);` makes it separate from the `{ }` block below it. So it's stuck in an infinite loop. 
Also, `x *= x` is not a correct way to compute the power, as the `x` used in the next iteration will be the changed value from this iteration instead of the original input.

Comment: How dupe *`"Find length of string in C (without using strlen)"`* is related to the question? Reopened.

Comment: moortje, Rather than `x *= x;`, see [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).  `Function exp_by_squaring_iterative(x, n)  if n = 0 then return 1  y := 1; while n > 1 do  if n is even then   x := x * x;  n := n / 2;  else  y := x * y;  x := x * x;  n := (n – 1) / 2;   return x * y`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use functions
2. you have `;` past the `while` and your code in braces is not executed in the loop
3. use a larger integer type as the result as a "normal" unsigned int will wraparound quickly.
4. `x *= x` is definitely wrong.

```
unsigned long long mypow(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
    unsigned long long result = 1;
    while(y--) result *= x;
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned x, y;

    scanf("%u,%u", &x, &y);

    printf("%u ^ %u = %llu\n", x, y, mypow(x, y));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xzx8Mo5aW

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to integrate what  you've suggested. And I should've given more thought to x *= x. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    unsigned int long x; // assign x
    printf_s("Enter value for x: "); // prompt
    scanf_s("%u", &x); // read input

    unsigned int y; // assign y
    printf_s("Enter value for y: "); // prompt
    scanf_s("%u", &y); // read input

    unsigned int count = 0; // initialize count
    unsigned int power = 1; // initialize power
    while (count < y) // loop while y is less than count
    {
        power *= x; // multiply power by x
        count++; // increment count

    } // loop ends

    printf_s("x raised to the power of y is: %u", power); // display result
}
```

I've deleted ;.
I've added long to unsigned int.
I've set up a new variable, power, in order to contain the value of x raised to a power of y.
I've checked if this works when y = 0 or 1 and it does.
Thank you everyone for your help!

P.S. Textbook answer has pritnf( "%s", "Enter first integer: "); for prompting for the first integer, x. I'm not sure why they add %s as it works perfectly fine without it. Does anyone know why one would add %s?

Comment: Textbook's code is probably a refactoring of a more complex process that missed this simplification. There probably is no real reason for it.

Comment: `iostream` is for C++ not C   Suggest using`#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: this is the prototype for `printf()`   printf FORMAT [ARGUMENT]...
  the `"%s" is the format parameter

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. The people in site is so helpful that it's almost hard to believe. Thank you Neil for explaining why they had %s. Thank you user3629249 for pointing out that I was not using correct header file and clarifying printf().